# Unable to initialize org agenda with log on Emacs startup

Tags: org-agenda, hooks, start-up

I have been able to initialize org agenda on Emacs startup with:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'org-agenda-list)
```

However, now I want to initialize org agenda directly with log mode, and I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

Attempting to write

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed clock))
```

resulted in an Emacs error about the symbol `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` being void. I guess it's because `org-mode` related functions haven't been completely loaded yet on Emacs startup.

However, attempts to run it after org has been loaded have also failed:

```
(eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  '(org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed clock)))
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-agenda-list` is a function, but `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode` is just a variable.  What you appear to want to do is call `org-agenda-list` with a certain value for `org-agenda-start-with-log-mode`.  You can do this is as follows:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (let ((org-agenda-start-with-log-mode '(closed clock)))
          (org-agenda-list))))
```

with the `let` clause creating a local binding.